# Will bootloader for armv7 work for armv8?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, beagleboneblack, armv7, armv8

I am trying to write a bootloader according to armv7 architecture using armv7 assembly instruction set ?
Ex:

Setting cpu to svc mode on reset:

```
mrs r0, cpsr
bic r0, r0,#0x1f
orr r0, r0,#0xd3
msr cpsr, r0
mov pc, lr
```

Will the same bootloader work on armv8. As armv8 also supports aarch32 .
But on the other hand it also has many differences.

Comment: it already boots into svc mode right? why set to svc mode if it is already there. ARMv7: "A processor enters Supervisor mode on Reset."

Comment: In an implementation where the highest implemented Exception level is using AArch32, if that
Exception level is EL3 or EL1, a PE enters Supervisor mode on Reset.

Comment: Ill let you read the rest on your own, or just read out the cpsr on boot as early as you can and save it or view it...

Comment: Thanks..upon reset it should already be in svc.i have taken these lines from uboot. Dont know why it is exactly needed .

Comment: Its true in hyp and aarch64 ,i m stuck.What if it is not in hyp and the execution state is aarch32 ?.I am trying to replace uboot with mine for beaglebone black which is v8.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
BBB is cortex-A8 which has armv7-a micro-architecture.

Comment: very early on in your bootloader simply read it then display it there or leave it so you can read it with a debugger, etc...THEN...try to understand why it is or isnt in some mode so that you can then put it in the mode you like.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily for a couple of reasons, first off if you are in hyp mode you cant get back from that that easily.  Second, if you are in aarch64 mode then that is a different instruction set.  So in part it depends on where this code is how early in the bootloader is this truly the bootloader or do you have other code that comes before this (that puts you in a state that code like this won't work).

Short answer, no this code not only won't always work for armv8 it won't always work for armv7.